Entire functions which satisfy a coefficient property
Let $f$ be an entire function. Then we can write $$f(z) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n z^n$$ for some $c_0, c_1, \ldots$.
For a positive real $r$, let $$M_r = \sup \{ |f(z)| : |z| = r \}$$.
The questions are:
(i) Explain why we have $$|c_n| \leq \frac{M_r}{r^n}$$ for all $n$
(ii) Now let $n$ and $r$ be fixed. For which entire functions $f$ do we have $$|c_n| = \frac{M_r}{r^n}?$$
I wanted to check if my answers were correct (mostly for (ii)).
(i)$$|c_n| = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int_{|w| = r} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi r \sup_{|w| = r}\left|\frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}\right| = \frac{M_r}{r^n}$$
(ii) $$ |c_n| = \frac{M_r}{r^n} \iff \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int_{|w| = r} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw\right| = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi r \sup_{|w| = r}\left|\frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}\right| \iff \left|\int_{|w| = r} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw\right| = \cdot 2\pi r \sup_{|w| = r}\left|\frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}\right| \iff \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} = c, c\in \mathbb{C} \iff f(z) = c z^{n+1}$$

I think the problem is when you have the integral equal to the $\sup$ , you won't have $f(z) = cz^{n+1}$ - Take $n=r=1$ then your solution yields $f(z) = cz^2$, which is wrong. Since your question just ask for the equality of Cauchy's estimate, see a discussion here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065632/the-cauchy-estimate#:~:text=The%20Cauchy%20Estimate%20is%20an,%3D1%2C2%2C%E2%80%A6.
